# how to update DIV content (such as cart DIV)

Tags: php, javascript

I used `$.load()` function to load the cart details. However, when I click on the add link, it only show details with that specific id in my shopping cart. And it seems that the shopping cart is created every time when trying to add one item.

```
Code for add button: 
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="recp('.$row["id"].')" >
```

Script:

```
function recp(id) {
$('.bottomcorners').load('addToCart.php?id=' + id);
}

</script>

AddToCart function
$conn = mysql_connect ('localhost','root','') or die("Unable to connect to mysql database server");
mysql_select_db('itech7602', $conn) or die ("Unable to select database");
$id = $_GET['id'];

echo $id;
//Check if the ID variable is set
if(isset($id))
{

    //Escape the string from the URL
    $ID = mysql_real_escape_string($id);

    //Check if the ID passed exists within the database
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = "'.$ID.'" LIMIT 1');

    //Get the total results of if any product matched the query
    $totalRows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    //If the product ID exists in the database then insert it to the cart
    if($totalRows > 0)
    {

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {

            //Check if the cart exists
            if(cartExists())
            {

                //The cart exists so just add it to the cart
                insertToCart($ID, $row['name'], $row['price']);

            }
            else
            {

                //The cart doesn't exist so create the cart
                createCart();

                //The cart is now created so add the product to the cart
                insertToCart($ID, $row['name'], $row['price']);

            }

        }

    }
    else
    {

        //No products were found in the database so notify the user, redirect him and stop the code from continuing
        //notify('Sorry but there is no product with that ID.', 0);
        echo ("No item with that ID");
        //header('Location: store.php');

    }

    //The product was successfully added so set the notification and redirect to the cart page
    //notify('Product added to the cart.', 1);
    echo ("Product added to the cart.");
    //header('Location: store.php');

}
else
{

    //No Product with that ID redirect and display message
    //notify('Sorry but there is no product with that ID.', 0);
    echo "Add Failed!";
    //header('Location: store.php');

}
getCart();
exit();
?>
```

Functions like insertToCart, getCart() are all declared in another php script named functions.php.

Any suggestion?

I tried to use `InnerHTML`, but get no luck

function addPro(id){

```
// This will create the XmlHttpRequest in modern browsers
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();                   
}
// This will create the XmlHttpRequest in older versions of Internet Explorer
else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

// This is how you tell the script what to do with the response from the request
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("bottomcorners").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "addToCart.php?id="+id, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: please put code for `cartExists()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="recp('.$row["id"].')" >
```

Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="recp('<?php echo $row["id"];?>')" >
```

Comment: Hey guy, it doesn't work for me. The error message is "unexpected '?' By the way this "<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="recp('.$row["id"].')" > is alread in a php, the recp can get my id. The problem so far is that it would not update the cart content. I just show the one I am clicking it. In other words, it just show one item. Eg, I click on apple, it shows me apple, and it also works for me when i click on banana.